# Why do I get "StopIteration" when searching for a string in an input file?

Tags: python, string, input, text

In my work we have a text file that's created by software. I want to create a script that can be run from command line, that is run against an input file, scan for the string "Item Value:" and print the values after the keyword on that line to a new text file.

This doesn't work, but this is what I have come up with by reading other questions on here:

```
import sys
inFile = sys.argv[1]
outFile = sys.argv[2]

with open(inFile,'r') as i:
    lines = i.readlines()

with open(inFile, 'r') as f:
    while not 'Item Value:' in next(f):
        pass
    for lines in f:
        print(lines)

with open(outFile,'w') as o:
    for lines in f:
        o.write(lines)
```

When I attempt to run through CL like this:

```
python pythonscript.py inputfile.txt output.txt
```

I get this error:

```
 File "pythonscript.py", line 10, in <module>
 while not 'Item Value:' in next(f):
 StopIteration
```

Current code:

```
import sys
inFile = sys.argv[1]
outFile = sys.argv[2]

with open(inFile,'r') as i:
    lines = i.readlines()

with open(inFile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'Item value:' in line:
            break

    with open(outFile,'w') as o:
        for lines in f:
             o.write(lines)
```

Comment: Why are you opening and reading `inFile` two times?

Answer (score 0):

There's not really much of a reason to open the input file twice. For a quick and simple script you could do something like this:

```
import sys

f_name = sys.argv[1]
output_file = sys.argv[2]

with open(f_name, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        split_line = line.split(':')
        if split_line[0] == 'Item Value':
            print(split_line[1:])
            with open(output_file, 'w') as o:
                for output_item in split_line[1:]:
                    o.write(output_item)
            break
```

Please note, this makes assumptions about things like your intentions and what exactly your input data may look like.

Comment: I tried the above code, and I get no error through CL, but it does not generate an output file.

Comment: What is the error you get? Its most likely due to the format of your input file

Answer (score 0):

Calling `next` will advance an iterator to the next step, and when it has reached the end it will raise `StopIteration`.

This means that none of the lines in `f` contained the string `'Item Value:'`.

Normally you should not call `next` manually. The idiomatic way to consume an iterator is by using a `for` loop which will handle the `StopIteration` under the hoods (by ending the loop).

So you should replace this

> ```
> while not 'Item Value:' in next(f):
>     pass
> ```

by this:

```
for line in f:
    if 'Item Value:' in line:
        break
```

---

Once you have fixed this, and assuming that the input file actually contains the string `'Item Value:'`, you will notice that the output file will be empty in any case.

There are two reasons for this.

First, because of these two lines:

> ```
> for lines in f:
>     print(lines)
> ```

Now `f` has been consumed completely, and when trying to iterate over it again in

> ```
> for lines in f:
>     o.write(lines)
> ```

nothing will happen anymore.

Second, when you call `o.write(lines)`, `f` has already been closed because you have left the `with` block that opened it.

The simplest way to fix this would be to just replace the loop where you call `print` by the code where you open and write the output file:

```
with open(inFile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'Item Value:' in line:
            break

    with open(outFile, 'w') as o:
        for lines in f:
            o.write(lines)
```

Notice how the second `with` block is nested inside the first `with` block, so that the output file is written while the input file is still open (because it still needs to read from it).

Comment: Using your above script, I generate an empty output.txt file

Comment: Because the input file didn't contain `Item Value:`. That's what caused the original error, too.

Comment: Ok, I now have it put data in the output file, but its including everything after the first "Item value:" keyword hit.  What I need is for it to read the input file for "Item value:" and put just the string immediately after that keyword into a text file, find the next "Item value:" hit and repeat process.

Comment: I will post my current code in original question. Thanks so much for this!